# How to set a lower height of react-date-range year dropdown in Calendar component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, css-selectors

I am specifically using https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/#calendar in my project and although i have mostly modified the css i cannot find how would i lower the height ( or change the number options available when you first open it and have a scroll )

[image]

I have tried to use max height on the relevant classes
.rdrYearPicker select but it is not working.

Comment: could you please add sandbox example for your problem, so we could have a better look on the issue.

Comment: Just as the previous comment requested a sandbox code - that would make it easier to find a solution. Other than that the logical CSS thing to do styling-wise is add `maxHeight` property and `overflow: "auto"` to enable scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to defines ranges in array of range object.